# Running 10 kotlin async coroutines concurrently

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

**I am trying to run 7 async coroutines concurrently but only 4 async coroutines seems to be running**

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        var urls = arrayOf(mUrl,mUrl2,mUrl3,mUrl4,mUrl5,mUrl5,mUrl5)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {

            for(url in urls){
                async { getlocationSourcecode(url) }  // This is jsoup parsing html method 
            }
            Log.i("MainActivity", " TEST : This Main coroutine is running in ${Thread.currentThread().name} thread ")
        }

    })
```

**This is my log where you can see only 4 threads are working**

```
   2020-05-02 16:52:15.177 11578-11578/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This Main thread is running in main thread 
2020-05-02 16:52:20.759 11578-11674/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 thread 
2020-05-02 16:52:20.762 11578-11676/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 thread 
2020-05-02 16:52:20.763 11578-11675/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 thread 
2020-05-02 16:52:20.765 11578-11673/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 thread 
2020-05-02 16:52:22.977 11578-11674/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 thread 
2020-05-02 16:52:23.761 11578-11674/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 thread 
2020-05-02 16:52:24.393 11578-11674/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 thread 
2020-05-02 16:53:43.252 11578-11675/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 thread 
2020-05-02 16:55:22.039 11578-11673/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 thread 
2020-05-02 16:55:22.453 11578-11673/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 thread 
2020-05-02 16:55:22.923 11578-11673/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 thread 
2020-05-02 16:55:23.397 11578-11675/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 thread 
2020-05-02 16:55:23.863 11578-11675/com.example.android.iscrape I/MainActivity:  TEST : This Main coroutine is running in DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 thread
```

**This is the initial part of the jsoup method with also parses json**

Here i have logged the thread name to check how many threads are running

```
suspend fun getlocationSourcecode(url: String) {

    lateinit var trying: String

    Log.i("MainActivity", "TEST : getDatax  called ")
    Log.i("MainActivity", " TEST : This asyncTask thread is running in ${Thread.currentThread().name} thread ")
```

Comment: There can't be more concurrent processes than there are cores on your devices, which is probably 4.

Comment: But i have 8 cores in my phone,   and there are some tutorials where you can run 10k coroutines how is that so

Comment: @JowelTisso they all don't run parallel at single instance of time. 1 billion task can be performed in just a second since there are processor with gigahertz of clock speed. But it doesn't mean all can be done that efficiently, apparently tutorials you've seen would have been of delay and some on-processor tasks, which does not require so much of processing time. It's worth noting that for your processor has 8 cores there should be 8 (max) default dispatching threads available. if you want higher number of threads consider using Dispatchers.IO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Dispatchers.Default` as the coroutine dispatcher. Quoting [the documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html):

> It is backed by a shared pool of threads on JVM. By default, the maximum number of threads used by this dispatcher is equal to the number of CPU cores, but is at least two.

Based on your Logcat output, it would appear that you are running on a quad-core CPU, as there appears to be four threads in the `Dispatchers.Default` thread pool.

You are welcome to use `Executors.newThreadPoolExecutor()` to create a thread pool with more threads on it, then use the `asCoroutineDispatcher()` extension function on `Executor` to wrap it in a `CoroutineDispatcher` for you to use instead of `Dispatchers.Default`. However, unless your work is I/O bound, that is probably unnecessary on a mobile device. And, for I/O bound work, you should be considering [`Dispatchers.IO`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html), which shares threads with `Dispatchers.Default` but also uses an auxiliary thread pool with many more threads in it.

Comment: Apparently i have 8 cores in my phone, and i saw i some tutorials running 10000 coroutines at a time, how is that possible then, doesn't that requires cpu cores  `fun creatingCoroutines(){
        val time = measureTimeMillis {
            runBlocking {
                for(i in 1..100000) {
                    launch {
                        delay(10000L)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @JowelTisso Try using a delay in `getlocationSourcecode`. Maybe just logging the thread isn't long enough so workers get reused at the end? Also, when I want to do something like this I usually use `awaitAll()`: `urls.map { async { doSomething() } }.awaitAll()` (not sure if that changes anything).

Comment: @JowelTisso: "and i saw i some tutorials running 10000 coroutines at a time" -- no, you saw them invoking 10000 coroutines at time. They were not running at the same time. You are confusing concurrency (code that *could* execute at the same time) with parallelism (code that *is* executing at the same time).

Comment: @Nicolas Isn't delay a mimic for the time taken to fetch the json data or any network call. And can you explain how 10k coroutines works

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok i didn't know much about that difference, will read on it more, and what about the cores, atleast 7 should be running as i have 8 cores.

Comment: @JowelTisso I'm not an expert, but basically any coroutine can get paused at some point of their execution so that the dispatcher can continue running another coroutine. So you never get 10k coroutines running "at the same time", there's always only a certain number, say 4, running at the same time (each on a separate core), but these 4 constantly change. So it's multitasking more than multithreading.

Comment: @JowelTisso: "Ok i didn't know much about that difference, will read on it more, and what about the cores, atleast 7 should be running as i have 8 cores" -- I am not aware of any mobile device with 8 *simultaneous* cores. The typical approach for mobile CPUs is to have 8 cores of varying speeds, but only use 4 at a time. See the ARM big.LITTLE architecture, for example.